# Como importar/exportar categorias no Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, magento

Estou tentando importar os produtos e categorias de uma loja para outra, mas no magento só existe a opção de exportar apenas os produtos e clientes.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira que encontrei até hoje, de fazer isso é usando esse script

http://www.atensoftware.com/p187.php

só realizar o cadastro que o site te dá um php que exporta seus produtos em uma planilha csv

as categorias vem em json, vc pode extrair e formatar as mesmas para o formato

```
categoria pai/categoria filho
```

e importar usando magmi com plugin on the fly categorie importer.

é trabalhoso, e não muito prático ainda, mas funciona.

se alguém tiver uma solução melhor por favor compartilhe!

Comment: Obrigado! vou tentar utilizar essa maneira. Não sabia que era tão complicado algo que parecia ser tão simples, apenas um backup o_o